# Максимальная длина url в IE

Tags: php, url, internet-explorer

Прочитал в сети, что максимальная длина url в IE равно 2048 символов. Но, мне, почему-то на запрос, в url которого всего 300 символов, выдает следующую ошибку в попапе

> Длина URL-адреса этого файла слишком велика для данного приложения. На компьютере будет открыта временная копия этого файла. Копию необходимо сохранить как новый файл.

Есть ли возможность как-то обойти эту ошибку, не меняя структуры папок. То бишь, чтобы путь остался тем же?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URL-адрес, содержащий более 260 знаков не поддерживается. Кроме того не поддерживается URL-адрес, содержащий один или несколько из следующих компонентов:

- Имя папки, которая имеет более чем 256 символов UCS-2
- Имя файла, который имеет длину более 128 знаков

Создайте новый документ в библиотеке документов или сохранить существующий документ в библиотеке документов, используя новое имя для документа.